# Amplifier Transfer Characteristics

Tags: voltage, amplifier, power-electronics, gain

In a previous question I had this as the given:

> 1. The transfer characteristics of a voltage amplifier are described by the following equation:
>      vO = F + G vI with amplifier saturation levels at vO = –3 V and at vO = +5 V.
>      The input voltage vI = 0.4 sin(t) V produces an undistorted output with the largest peak-to-peak
>      value, which is vO = C + 4 sin(t) V. Find the value of G (in V/V).

By taking the midpoint $$\frac{(L- L-)}{2} = 4V$$ Then we divide by G, the gain we're looking for to get 0.4 V.
$$ \frac{4}{Gain} = 0.4$$

So the Gain = 10 V/V

In the following question we need to find F. The answer according to the key is 1, I've only managed to prove that F = C but that gets me nowhere.

Comment: "0.4 sin(t) V produces an undistorted output with the largest peak-to-peak value" is the key to finding F.

Comment: Vswing-Vmean=F....